# How do I apply multiple columns in GroupBy/PartitionBy in Spark Java API

Tags: java, apache-spark

If I have a list/Seq of columns in **Scala** like:

```
val partitionsColumns = "p1,p2"
val partitionsColumnsList = partitionsColumns.split(",").toList
```

I can easily use it in `partitionBy` or `groupBy` like

```
val windowFunction = Window.partitionBy(partitionsColumnsList:_*)
    .orderBy(df("some_date").desc)
```

But if I want to do the same thing in Spark Java API what should I do?

```
List<String> partitions = new ArrayList<>();
partitions.add("p1");
partitions.add("p2");

WindowSpec windowSpec  = Window.partitionBy(.....)
    .orderBy(desc("some_date"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`partitionBy` has two signatures:

```java
partitionBy(Seq<Column> cols)
partitionBy(String colName, Seq<String> colNames)
```

So you may choose between one of the two. Let's say that `partitions` is a list of String. It would go like this:

```java
import scala.collection.JavaConversions;
import scala.collection.Seq;

List<Column> columns = partitions.stream()
    .map(functions::col)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
Seq<Column> columnSeq = JavaConversions.asScalaBuffer(columns).toSeq();
WindowSpec windowSpec  = Window.partitionBy(columnSeq);

// OR
Seq<String> columnSeq2 = JavaConversions.asScalaBuffer(partitions).toSeq();
WindowSpec windowSpec  = Window
    .partitionBy(partitions.get(0), columnSeq2.tail().toSeq());
```

Comment: Dear Oli, in spark-sql 2.11 it has four signatures.

Comment: All right, then you have four solutions :-D

Answer (score -1):

Some IDEs such as *IntelliJIdea* support Scala and Java and when you copy a Java code in a Scala class, it will convert code gracefully.

However, you can use the following for your desired operation in Java:

```
WindowSpec windowSpec  = Window.partitionBy("p1","p2").orderBy(col("some_date").desc());
```

If you need a list of columns you can send a Seq to partitionBy method:

```
List<Column> partitions = new ArrayList<>();
partitions.add(col("p1"));
partitions.add(col("p2"));

Seq<Column> seqPartitions = JavaConverters.asScalaIteratorConverter(partitions.iterator()).asScala().toSeq();
WindowSpec windowSpec  = Window.partitionBy(seqPartitions).orderBy(col("some_date").desc());
```

Comment: I don't want to pass string one by one I want to pass an array!

Comment: You didn't say this. Just say need it in Java. However, you cannot pass an array of String. You can just pass an array of Seq.